# Redirect to internal web-directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, document-root

I already found this script to "change the documentroot":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.your-domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !new-folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /new-folder/$1 [L]
```

It's simple and cool, but I want to complement the script. I want to redirect to the file /new-folder/index.php if the requested file does not exist **inside the directory /new-folder/**, so not only `%{REQUEST_URI} !-f`!
But I don't know how to get the current script-path, like `__DIR__` (PHP) in .htaccess.
So my question is, **how to check if a file exists inside a subdirectory (new-folder)?**
My redirect will theoretically look like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.your-domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !./new-folder/
RewriteCond (PATH+Filename, if no filename is set, take index.php) !-f
RewriteRule (.*) ./new-folder/index.php [L]
```

The above code uses ./ to check relative, it does not know if it's inside the root!

Also I would like to manipulate the REQUEST_URI: replace the /new-folder/ from it, so scripts inside this folder don't have to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?your-domain-name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/new-folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new-folder/$1 !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new-folder/$1 !-d [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /new-folder/index.php [L]
```

Another option is use this in any sub-directory `/anydirectory/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:BASE}new-folder/$1 !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:BASE}new-folder/$1 !-d [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:BASE}new-folder/index.php [L]
```

Comment: this assumes that the .htaccess is inside the root

Comment: I want to use the .htaccess-file in a superordinate level, but not inside the documentroot. So the .htaccess is in /test/ and the script should check /test/new-folder/$1

Comment: this is beautiful and I would like to thank you. The only problem is, that also in this case as in all other cases from me /test/ is a a variable. I don't know if it's really inside /test/ it could also be inside the root / or inside /hello/world/ . That is why I have used ./new-folder/ in my first post, to make it relative

Comment: +1 THANK you very much! This BASE-trick seems to do anything I want!!

Comment: A thing yet: the negative does not work in the case. The redirect should go if the file does does not exist, your code redirects if it does exist. But if I use `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:BASE}new-folder/$1 !-f [NC]` with !-f it will throw an Internal Error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That does not meet my notions. I'm doing the whole thing to make files in the requested directory private, so no one can access them, only via ftp. But you check if the files exist in the requested directory. But that does not matter, it's all about wheter the file exist inside a web/ director (called in the example /new-directory/ or any other subdirectory).The task of the script is to redirect the user internal to the file if it exists inside the /new-directory/. If not, redirect to the index.php inside /new-directory/. That's all.

Comment: Everything is per your requirement only. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is there to stop rewriting after writing to `%{ENV:BASE}new-folder/index.php`

Comment: No, I see a few problems. If I request /somedir/ it should redirect to /somedir/new-folder/index.php, but it calls /somedir/index.php. Also if I request /somedir/test.php and the test.php exists inside /somedir/new-folder/ if will not redirect to it, instead it will redirect to the /somedir/new-folder/index.php. Also if I request a file what actually exists inside /somedir/ it will show it! But that is wrong! I think `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is responsible for the last error.

Comment: `If I request /somedir/ it should redirect to /somedir/new-folder/index.php, but it calls /somedir/index.php.` That is already happening in my 2nd `/anydirectory/.htaccess` above. Are you sure you're not using both the solutions? You just need to use `/anydirectory/.htaccess` code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52168/discussion-between-user3292653-and-anubhava)

Comment: You're there? Let's continue in chat

Comment: Hey, please reply in the chat